# How do I pull changed file names from a git commit and put them as variables in an ftp upload command

Tags: command-line, git, ftp

I need to ftp files on a regular basis, even though I still use git to update a code base. So, the workflow is I do my git work and then use Cyberduck to connect and ftp the same files to basically a duplicate structure. blech.

I would like to make this easier.

As a mac user, in one command, I would like to take the file names (paths?) that were changed in a commit and ftp them to a location.

Comment: See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/20267  Then maybe use a relative ref like `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD^`